# What is the recommended limit for memory usage in Android applications?

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

Is there is a recommended limit for memory usage in Android applications? Like it should be below 40 MBs or something.. Sometimes my application uses up to 100 MBs in Android Monitor when I load heavy items (news feed with videos) into recyclerview and I wonder if there is some normal memory usage size which we should follow.

Comment: The recommendation is: as less as you can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use as little as you can.**

> To allow multiple running processes, Android sets a hard limit on the
>   heap size alloted for each app. The exact heap size limit varies
>   between devices based on how much RAM the device has available
>   overall. If your app has reached the heap capacity and tries to
>   allocate more memory, the system throws an ***OutOfMemoryError***.
>
> To avoid running out of memory, you can to query the system to
>   determine how much heap space you have available on the current
>   device. You can query the system for this figure by calling
>   ***getMemoryInfo()***. This returns an ***ActivityManager.MemoryInfo*** object
>   that provides information about the device's current memory status,
>   including available memory, total memory, and the memory threshold—the
>   memory level below which the system begins to kill processes. The
>   ***ActivityManager.MemoryInfo*** class also exposes a simple ***boolean*** field,
>   lowMemory that tells you whether the device is running low on memory.
>
> The following code snippet shows an example of how you can use the
>   ***getMemoryInfo()***. method in your application.

```
public void doSomethingMemoryIntensive() {

    // Before doing something that requires a lot of memory,
    // check to see whether the device is in a low memory state.
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = getAvailableMemory();

    if (!memoryInfo.lowMemory) {
        // Do memory intensive work ...
    }
}

// Get a MemoryInfo object for the device's current memory status.
private ActivityManager.MemoryInfo getAvailableMemory() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    return memoryInfo;
}
```

Refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#code) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation is to use as less as possible.
How to achieve that??

- Handling bitmaps properly(In most of the cases you may want to use a 3rd
  party library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso),[Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)).
- Use heap dump in android-studio and analyze what is consuming your ram and check for activity leaks.
- If you are requesting lots of data from the network then you can have look at [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) they will reduce the memory footprint and payload of a network request
- Not using deep view hierarchies